# Printer Language for hp printer in android

Tags: java, android, printing

I am using Zebra SDK to connect and print using printers.
Now if suppose there is zebra printer then it will connect and print file and if suppose another printer like hp , canon then it will not connect with printer.
So what may be problem ? 
I think this is because of different printing language used by printers.
So how can i solved it ?

Comment: your question is far too general... btw: not all HP printers have the same language, neither do all canon printers... and: it is not only a question of "printer language" but among other things a question of "communication protocol"...

Comment: @YAhia :Which protocol used to communication with printer ? Is there any library availabe for android to print file ?

Comment: The protocol can differ too... if you want a library that supports different printer see for example http://www.iprintsdk.com/supported_printers.html

Comment: @Yahin : iPrint is not a free library for android. Is there any free library for android ?

Comment: I don't know of any - perhaps you should google for "Google Cloud Printing SDK"...

Comment: @Yahin:"Google Cloud Printing SDK" is another way for printing.but i want to directly print file from my phone using printer , No other PC should be required.Is it only possible with Bluetooth printer or wifi printer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5933/discussion-between-ramesh-solanki-and-yahia)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

try use HP PCL BT Printer protocol